# JNI Error accessed stale weak global reference

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am trying to call NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback from JNI layer.
As you must be aware the signature for the same is 
`setNdefPushMessageCallback(NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback callback, Activity activity, Activity... activities)`

I have gone through some references to this problem [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993239/jni-error-accessed-stale-weak-global-reference) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071585/error-jni-error-app-bug-accessed-stale-global-reference)

I have taken care of all those suggestions. I suspect it must be related to second one.

Here is my code :

```
    jmethodID methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(
    env, cls, "setNdefPushMessageCallback",
    "(Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter$CreateNdefMessageCallback;Landroid/app/Activity;[Landroid/app/Activity;)V");

(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, g_adapter, methodId, g_nfcCallback, g_activity);
```

In the place of [Landroid/app/Activity; (va_list), I am not giving any other argument.

In case of Java this is perfectly accepted :

```
NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(callback, activity);
```

Please suggest me the solution

Comment: Try to use a `NULL` reference for the expected vararg.

Comment: I have tried this already. I get the below error `08-28 09:19:46.161: E/AndroidRuntime(22601): Process: org.iotivity.ca.sample_service, PID: 22601
08-28 09:19:46.161: E/AndroidRuntime(22601): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
08-28 09:19:46.161: E/AndroidRuntime(22601):    at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(NfcAdapter.java:1279)`

Answer (score 0):

This method signature requires at least one Activity as arguments.
If you don't provide anything for the last `activities` argument, Java will automatically create a new empty array.
Unfortunately, the JNI layer won't do it automatically and the corresponding code will crash if it receive a null argument ([the foreach loop here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.java#1069)).

Therefore, you need to pass an empty array to the method call:

```
jobjectArray empty = (jobjectArray) (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 0, (*env)->FindClass(env, "Landroid/app/Activity;"), NULL);
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, g_adapter, methodId, g_nfcCallback, g_activity, empty);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marquis. Finally this has resolved the problem and seems to be the best way to do it. I still have a question on mind, that Does JNI allow to `NewObjectArray` with length 0?

I have a small correction to the implementation that you gave :

`jobjectArray tempArr = (jobjectArray) (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 0, (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/app/Activity"), NULL);`